# Maintaing a list of "must install" apps for new Android phones

Tags: applications, installation, factory-reset

Is there a option to maintain a list of must have apps which would always install on my phone when I loggin with that accounts email.
For example when you factory reset a phone or by a new one, it is really time consuming to remember and install all the needed apps by hand. How can I just say "hey phone, install this list of apps for me please".
edit : this apps need to be installed from google play not sd card

Comment: isn't there syncing option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read now that android 5.0 will support profiles akka list of apps that you want to install from the store automatically. This was the thing I needed!

Comment: And how can you do this?